# С++ Visual Studio 2022 Preview 5.0 показывает несуществующие ошибки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

После обновления Visual Studio появились ошибки.

> ```
> E0020 identifier “BOOST_PP_IIF_BOOST_PP_BOOL_” is undefined
> ```

Проект компилируется. Из за чего такое может быть? Откатывался на предыдущую версию и там ошибок не было.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

133 ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте добиться [mcve].

Comment: αλεχολυτ, В минимальном примере ошибок нет

Comment: αλεχολυτ, ошибки возникают при подключении через include библиотек boost

Comment: О проблемах с экспериментальными версиями Visual Studio следует писать разработчикам по каналам обратной связи программы предварительного доступа.

Comment: удалите .vs, это IntelliSense дурит

Comment: Для уведомления в комментарии надо добавлять символ собаки @ вплотную к имени уведомляемого. Иначе оповещения не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похожая проблема описана [тут](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/IntelliSens-reports-many-errors-for-the-/10287480). Возникает при использовании `<boost/concept_check.hpp>` в VS 17.5. Обходное решение так же описано в комментариях (добавить ключ сборки `/Zc:preprocessor`), но оно может не всегда помогать, т.к. порождает другую проблему с препроцессингом.

Пока фикса бага официально не выпущено, можно откатиться на предыдущую версию VS 17.4.X. Функционал отката версии доступен через Visual Studio Installer.